# apis.google.com has an invalid security certificate. How do I overcome this problem?

Tags: web-browser, dns-spoofing

This is a screenshot of my browser when I tried visiting my public calendar. It shows that apis.google.com has an invalid security certificate:

[image]

This means that there is some problem with my DNS right? What do I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: It would appear to mean that something is hijacking your requests to apis.google.com and trying to send them to quicksearch.website. There are too many possible ways for that to happen to be able to diagnose remotely though - a good starting point would be to remove any browser extensions and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: @Matthew, I have already did that. It doesn't help, I deleted all plugins, and restarted the browser, but the problem still persists.

Comment: As I said, there are lots of ways this could occur: hosts file could have been edited, could be DNS hijack, could be malware on machine adjusting requests as they are sent, could be that your router has been compromised, could be that your ISP has been compromised - it's impossible to say without detailed investigation.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the certificate is valid for "quicksearch.website". A simple [search for this name at google](https://www.google.com/search?q=quicksearch.website) shows you that this is malware. There a lots of information online about this specific malware and how to remove it, like [Spyware.QuickSearch - Removal](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2004-102018-0405-99&tabid=3).